# Reactjs: How can I print the selection item in my webpage?

Tags: reactjs

First of all, I am new in reactjs. How can I print the selection item in my webpage? This code print the output in the console but I want to print the output in the webpage screen. How can I do this?

´´´´

```
import React from 'react';

class FlavorForm extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {value: 'coconut'};

    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  }

  handleChange(event) {
    this.setState({value: event.target.value});
  }

  handleSubmit(event) {
    console.log('Your favorite flavor is: ' + this.state.value);
    event.preventDefault();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
        <label>
          Pick your favorite flavor:
          <select value={this.state.value} onChange={this.handleChange}>
            <option value="grapefruit">Grapefruit</option>
            <option value="lime">Lime</option>
            <option value="coconut">Coconut</option>
            <option value="mango">Mango</option>
          </select>
        </label>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />

      </form>
    );
  }
}

export default FlavorForm
```

´´´´

Answer (score 0):

Just add some html element that is bound to your "value" property, like this:

```
render() {
    return (
        <div>
            <h3>Flavor: {this.state.value}</h3>
            <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                <label>
                    Pick your favorite flavor:
              <select value={this.state.value} onChange={this.handleChange}>
                        <option value="grapefruit">Grapefruit</option>
                        <option value="lime">Lime</option>
                        <option value="coconut">Coconut</option>
                        <option value="mango">Mango</option>
                    </select>
                </label>
                <input type="submit" value="Submit" />

            </form>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. But I want to show the results after clicking the submit button. How can I do that?

Comment: Show the results where? The state.value changes on each onChange event, so any html element that is bound to it- will show the result, regardless of the form submission. I think that your confusion comes from not understanding that React is "declarative". You can read about it here: https://codeburst.io/declarative-vs-imperative-programming-a8a7c93d9ad2

Answer (score 0):

Not sure of the exact behavior you want, but you could keep a boolean that your state that shows/hides the text:

```
import React from 'react';

class FlavorForm extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      value: 'coconut',
      showFlavor: false // this controls whether or not the text is shown
    };

    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  }

  handleChange(event) {
    this.setState({value: event.target.value});
  }

  handleSubmit(event) {
    // console.log('Your favorite flavor is: ' + this.state.value);
    event.preventDefault();
    this.setState({ showFlavor: true }); // toggle on our boolean, note that in this example it never gets set back to false
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
        <label>
          Pick your favorite flavor:
          <select value={this.state.value} onChange={this.handleChange}>
            <option value="grapefruit">Grapefruit</option>
            <option value="lime">Lime</option>
            <option value="coconut">Coconut</option>
            <option value="mango">Mango</option>
          </select>
        </label>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />

        // text appears here only when state.showFlavor is true
        <span>{this.state.showFlavor ? `Your favorite flavor is: ${this.state.value}` : ''}</span>
      </form>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. This is what I expecting as output. Thanks a lot